# In Joomla -- how to change link text when article title changes?

Tags: joomla

This seems like it should be easy in any CMS, but so far I'm stumped.

Desired behavior:

- Write an article, giving it title AAA
- Write a second article, include link to first article (link text is "AAA")
- Revise / republish the first article, change its title from AAA to ZZZ
- The link to the first article is now "ZZZ", reflecting the changed title

The last step isn't happening.  The link text is still "AAA".

When the Joomla editor inserts a link to another article, it is creating a plain-jane HTML `<a>` tag.  Although the href refers to the article by ID, the link text appears to be static text set at link-create time.

That behavior makes sense for external links to other web sites; and may sometimes make sense for internal links to the current web site (i.e. the writer may want to supply an alternate title or attach the link to some other text) although often it won't. Joomla's own auto-generated pages, like category and blog pages, always use the up-to-date article title.

Is there a way to create article links that dynamically change anchor text as article titles change?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its possible to do dynamically.

The rereplacer extension by nonumber.nl enables you to update across the site:

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer

User Guide:
http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer/userguide#3.1_Simple-replacement